# Como imprimir desde codigo java en una impresora Brother-ql720nw

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda para imprimir en una impresora de etiquetas brother-ql720 desde codigo java usando el modo escp

He instalado los controladores que vienen con la impresora también el software p-touch

Desde el software p-touch reconoce el tamaño del papel e imprime sin ningún problema

He intentado el siguiente codigo sin exito 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573466/printer-doesnt-work-receiving-esc-p-commands

```
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterName;

public class PrintESC_P {   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintService printService = null;
    String printerName = "Brother QL-720NW";
    HashAttributeSet attributeSet = new HashAttributeSet();
    attributeSet.add(new PrinterName(printerName, null));
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, attributeSet);
    if (services.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Printer not found.");
    } else if (services.length > 1) {
        System.out.println("Found more than one printer. Only the first printer will be used.");
    }
    printService = services[0];
    System.out.println("Printer found: "+printService.getName());
    try {
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;          
        String _ESC_P_Code = "ESC i a 00h\r\n"  +
                "ESC @\r\n" +
                "ESC i L 01h\r\n" +
                "ESC ( C 02h 00h FCh 02h\r\n" +
                "ESC $ 2Bh 00h\r\n" +
                "ESC ( V 02h 00h 6Dh 01h\r\n" +
                "ESC k 0bh\r\n" +
                "ESC X 00h 64h 00h\r\n" +
                "PRINTER TEST\r\n" +
                "ESC i C\r\n" +
                "FF\r\n";
        SimpleDoc doc = new SimpleDoc(_ESC_P_Code.getBytes(), flavor, null);
        DocPrintJob job = printService.createPrintJob();
        job.print(doc, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Solo necesito un ejemplo de impresión de texto

Adjunto imagen de la salida del p-touch que es lo que quiero hacer desde el codigo java

[image: Salida p-touch]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la salida de tu aplicación? Por lo visto, en caso que "falle" te muestra los mensajes pertinentes.

Comment: En la consola me imprime Printer found: Brother QL-720NW pero no imprime nada yo esperaba que imprima el texto "PRINTER TEST"

Comment: Yo también tengo el mismo problema quiero imprimir desde java utilizando comandos esc/pos y tengo una impresora Brother QL-800. Si ya encontraste una solución te pido publiques tu código se te agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la clase [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#print(java.text.MessageFormat,%20java.text.MessageFormat,%20boolean,%20javax.print.PrintService,%20javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet,%20boolean)) deberías poder imprimir incluso texto formateado.

```
JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
jtp.setBackground(Color.white);
jtp.setText("text to print");
boolean show = true;
try {
    jtp.print(null, null, show, null, null, show);
} catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Espero sirva, saludos.

Comment: Probé con esto y me sale el siguiente error http://imgur.com/SBQhpLl

Comment: Al parecer el problema está en la configuración del rollo pero no se como hacer dicho cambio

Comment: @BlasPico conversa con un administrador de sistemas o alguien que esté encargado de la impresora para que la revise y pueda detectar qué problemas tiene. El problema que tienes no es de programación.

Comment: Asi es amigo, al parecer tu problema esta en el hardware